# How to combine 2 click events functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this and it works fine but I wanted to have a nicer way to do the same thing, possibly having one single function rather than 2 distinctive ones and save lines.
Just some more elegant way than so many lines. The 2 following functions look similar but what they do are slightly different as you can see.
Anyone? Thanks

```
$("#container").on({
"mouseenter": function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    }, 400);
    $(this).prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 0).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 1);
},
"mouseleave": function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0.3"
    }, 400);
    $(this).prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 1).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 0);
}
}, "img");

$("#container").on({
"mouseenter": function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0.3"
    }, 400);
},
"mouseleave": function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    }, 400);
}
}, ".gallery a img");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple selectors using comma `,` or the `add()` function:

```
$("#container, #container2, #container3")
```

## Update

```
$("#container, #container2, #container3").on({
"mouseenter": function (e) {
   var id = e.target.id;
   if (id === 'container') {
     // code for #container
   }
   else if (id === 'container2') {
     // code for #container2
   }
   else if (id === 'container3') {
     // code for #container3
   }
},
"mouseleave": function (e) {
   var id = e.target.id;
   if (id === 'container') {
     // code for #container
   }
   else if (id === 'container2') {
     // code for #container2
   }
   else if (id === 'container3') {
     // code for #container3
   }
}
}, "img");
```

Comment: ha, that's nice. But that would provide the rest of the code to both selectors, the 2 functions don't do the same thing in my case

Comment: @rob.m: In that case you will have to modify your code a bit using `if` conditions, updating answer.

Comment: ye if/else is the way i should be going most probably, just trying to save some lines

Comment: @rob.m: Since as you said some of your code isn't same, for those you will have to use conditions or create functions but for same/common code you will have to put those outside of conditions :)

Comment: this is very useful as it gives me space for future additions and is "human". Thanks a lot. I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating some general functions to handle most of these events.

For example:

```
function someEvent(container, opacity) 
{
    $(container).stop().animate({
        "opacity": opacity
    }, 400);
}


$("#container").on({
   "mouseenter": someFunction($(this), '0.3');
  },
   "mouseleave": someFunction($(this), '1');
  }
}, ".gallery a img");
```

Comment: yes general function are always good practice but if you double check my question and my code you'll see it does a bit more than giving 2 different opacities to selectors

Answer (score 1):

You could pull out the common code into two functions, 'brighten' and 'dim'

```
brighten = function(container,hasCaption) {
    container.stop().animate({opacity:1},400);
    if(hasCaption) {
        container.prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 0).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }
}

dim = function(container,hasCaption) {
    container.stop().animate({opacity:0.3},400);
    if(hasCaption) {
        container.prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 1).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 0);
    }
}
```

Then you event binding looks like:

```
$("#container").on({
    "mouseenter": function () { brighten($(this),true); },
    "mouseleave": function () { dim($(this),true); }
}, "img");

$("#container").on({
    "mouseenter": function () { dim($(this)); },
    "mouseleave": function () { brighten($(this)); }
}, ".gallery a img");
```

Comment: this is just another way round but it isn't saving me lines i suppose

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.
You have different opacities for each element, so it will be a problem if you have to make a `if` for each element, so the best way to do it is store it using [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

JS

```
jQuery('#container1').data('opacity', {'enter': 0.1, 'leave': 1});
jQuery('#container2').data('opacity', {'enter': 0, 'leave': 0.1});

jQuery('#container1, #container2').on({
    "mouseenter": function() {
        var $element = jQuery(this);
        $element.stop().animate({
            "opacity": $element.data('opacity').enter;
        }, 400);
        if($element.is('#container1')) {
            $element.prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 0).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }
    },
    "mouseleave": function() {
        var $element = jQuery(this);
        $element.stop().animate({
            "opacity": $element.data('opacity').leave;
        }, 400);
        if($element.is('#container1')) {
            $element.prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 1).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 0);
        }
    }
}, "img");
```

Comment: this is alright but I'm not really into getting data attr, i mean, yes but i just don't want to rely to more html markup. It can get tricky with dynamic content as I probably end actually adding lines of code to assign those data attributes to html elements

Comment: @rob.m So, you can store with `jQuery.data()` like my updated answer.

Comment: @Riccardo Lohmann thanks, saving data is definitely a better idea but as per my comment to the other answer below, in this example you'll assign the caption bit to both occasions, which isn't what it is needed

Answer (score 1):

not tested:
Anyway it is better to keep code in a namespace and just call respective functions from events.

```
$("#container").on({
"mouseenter": function () {
    var galleryImg = $(this).parents('.gallery').length >=1;
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": galleryImg? 0.3 : 1
    }, 400);
    if(!gallerImg)$(this).prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 0).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 1);
},
"mouseleave": function () {
   var galleryImg = $(this).parents('.gallery').length >=1;
    $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": galleryImg? 1 : 0.3
    }, 400);
    if(!gallerImg)$(this).prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 1).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 0);
}
}, "img");
```

Comment: from your code i undesrstood first binding is for all 'img' inside #container and second for '.gallery a img' inside #container,

Comment: precisely yes, yours looks nice actually

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers are probably more elegant, but if you just want to reduce the number of lines and reduce duplication, you could break it off into a reusable function and call it twice like so:

```
function imageMouseover(selector, filterSelector, mouseEnterOpacity, mouseLeaveOpacity, fadeCaption) {
    $(selector).on({
        "mouseenter": function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "opacity": mouseEnterOpacity
            }, 400);
            if (fadeCaption) {
                $(this).prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 0).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 1);
            }
        },
        "mouseleave": function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "opacity": mouseLeaveOpacity
            }, 400);
            if (fadeCaption) {
                $(this).prev(".caption").stop().fadeTo(0, 1).css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo('fast', 0);
            }
        }
    }, filterSelector);
}
```

You can call it twice specifying just the stuff that's changing:

```
imageMouseover("#container", "img", "1", "0.3", true);
imageMouseover("#container", ".gallery a img", "0.3", "1", false);
```

Comment: this ia nice but if you look at my code, it actually has a bit more than just 2 different opacities for 2 different classes, that's where it gets challenging

Comment: Ah sorry so it does. I've updated the example with the caption part. It really depends on what level of customisation you're after - if each call will be significantly different or you need it to be more flexible then this might not be the right approach

Comment: this is better, yet one part has the caption while the other one doesn't, in this example you'll assign the caption bit to both occasions tho

Comment: The caption lines will only execute in the first call to the function and not the second. They're inside an if block based on the value of fadeCaption which is passed in as the final argument to the function (true and false respectively)

Comment: i see, well then this is the best actually as I could just call the function anywhere. Brilliant, thanks a lot